# Strange combinatorics task.

Tags: combinatorics

A car number plate in a strange country is made out of 5 signs the following way: The first 2 signs are made out of 22 alphabetical letters. The next 3 are made out of the numbers 2,4,6,8. Three Identical numbers are excluded (222,444...).

My solution: 22*22*4*4*4 - 4 to calculate all combinations, then we subtract the four combinations of 222,444,666,888

= 30972

Answer in my maths book: 29040

Where is my mistake?

Comment: AA-222, AB-222, AC-222, ...

Comment: You need to subtract $4$ for each of the $22\times 22$ possibilities for the letters.

Comment: 22*22*(4*4*4-4)?

Comment: thank you very much